# how to find distance between SNP and gene based on gene model file

Tags: r

I have a list of gene-SNP associations,

```
SNP                 Name              FDR
BV2.2c01_19087 BV01r90087   1.1e-03
BV2.2c01_24065 BV01r99876  1.4e-04
```

I have a gene model file:

```
BV2.2c01    maker   CDS     21882   22007   .   -   0   ID=BV01r90087:cds;Parent=BV01r90087;
BV2.2c01    maker   exon    21882   22007   .   -   .   ID=BV01r99876:exon:2;Parent=BV01r99876;
```

I am trying to calculate the distance between SNP and gene based on the gene model file. For this, I used:

```
gene_model = rtracklayer::import("gene_models.gff")
File <- read.delim("SNP_gene.csv")
File <-
    cbind(setNames(data.frame(do.call(
        rbind, strsplit(File$SNP, "_")
    )), c("seqnames", "start")), File)
File <-
    GenomicRanges::makeGRangesFromDataFrame(File, keep.extra.columns = TRUE, end.field = "start")
    merge_result<-merge(gene_model, File, by="Name")
```

However, this does not result in what I wanted.

I want:

```
 SNP                 Name              FDR.        Distance
    BV2.2c01_19087 BV01r90087            1.1e-03     2795 (upstream)
    BV2.2c01_24065 BV01r99876            1.4e-04     2183 (downstream)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you be more specific about ‘distance between SNP and gene based on the gene model file’ means? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I want to calculate the distance between gene and SNP. I have start and end (column 4 and 5) distances for the genes in gene model file. So, I want to calculate how far the SNP is from the gene based on the start and end distance of the gene in gene model file.